# Nginx Server Inception, where to serve SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, docker

I have 3 servers.

[image: Like this]

Server A: Firewall server with nginx that redirects to server B or C according the server_name (Virtual Host), accessible from outside.

Server B: Web Server with [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), a reverse nginx-proxy that serves all docker web containers in that server, accessible through Server A.

Server C: Same as server B

Those are dedicated servers inside an office, people in the office access the company sites directly to server B or C, I want to configure ssl for the web sites in the infrastructure but I have 2 problems:

1.- If I configure the ssl in server A, people from inside the office cannot access the sites with https, because the access directly to server B or C.

2.- If I configure the sites from inside server B or C according [this](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#sni), the site shows redirect problems (too many redirects), at least from outside.

This is the config in server A to redirect to Server B:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name sites-in-serverB.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxxxxxx.log;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://serverB-IP/;
        }
}
```

**Same for serving Server C sites

Of course each container has it own nginx server (Yes, I really like nginx). So we're looking to 4 levels of nginx. [Inception!!](http://inception.davepedu.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure SSL on every sever. That way the public accessing the two via server A get SSL, and people accessing servers B and C get SSL. You can proxy_pass from server A whether the target is http or https.

However internal servers don't always need to be over SSL, in which case you can just secure server A.

You can use free Let's Encrypt certificates if you want to.